# Writing Classes

Tags: java, class

Ive been working to improve my java skills over the summer but I just cant figure what I am missing for this problem and what should I look at on the internet to solve this problem?

Write a class called NumberOfGoals that represents the total
        number of goals scored by a football team. The NumberOfGoals
        class should contain a single integer as instance data, representing
        the number of goals scored. Write a constructor to initialize
        the number of goals to zero. Write a method called setGoal
        that increments the value by one whenever a goal is scored,
        and another method called getGoal that returns the total number
        of goals scored so far. Finally, create a driver class called
        GoalTracker that creates a few NumberOfGoals objects and tests
        their methods.

```
    public class ChapterFourProblem1 {

    int goalsscored;


public ChapterFourProblem1(int numberofgoals){

goalsscored= numberofgoals=0; }

public int setGoal() {
    return goalsscored++; }


public int getGoal() {
    return goalsscored;
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: It is almost correct, as far as I can see; `numberofgoals` is superfluous in the constructor, and you seem to be missing some closing braces. You are also missing `GoalTracker`. Also, note that your code is very hard to read, and most people will not want to bother trying to read it. Indentation is optional to the compiler, but it is vital if you expect other people (or indeed yourself) to read the code. Google up a Java Style Guide and stick to it.

Comment: IMO, your constructor does not fulfill the requirements. It should just initialize with zero but not have a parameter "numberofgoals" (which in fact is currently useless in your code).

Comment: Your class name is wrong to begin with. ChapterFourProblem1 should be used as your driver class name. Try to indent your codes properly, it makes it hard for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that difficult.

```
public class NumberOfGoals {
           int goalsScored;
           public NumberOfGoals(){
                goalsScored= 0; 
            }
           public void setGoal() {
              goalsScored++; 
           }
           public int getGoal() {
              return goalsScored;
           }
     }
```

This is basically all you have to do. 
Just have a look at this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) to have a basic concept with java.

In the main method, you can create the ChapterfourProblem1 object and call the methods

```
public GoalTracker{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       NumberOfGoals goal = new NumberOfGoals()
       NumberOfGoals goal2 = new NumberOfGoals()
       NumberOfGoalsgoal3 = new  NumberOfGoals()
            goal.setGoal();
           System.out.println(goal.getGoal());
        }
}
```

Comment: i just pointed out the obvious explanation to the problem at hand. My apologizes for the incorrect getGoal usage.  It has been updated

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NumberOfGoals {

    int goalsScored;

   public NumberOfGoals(){
       goalsScored = 0;
   }

    public void setGoal() {
        goalsScored++;
    }

    public int getGoal() {
       return goalsScored;
    }

}

public class GoalTracker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NumberOfGoals team1 = new NumberOfGoals();
        NumberOfGoals team2 = new NumberOfGoals();

        System.out.println(team1.getGoal());

        team2.setGoal();

        System.out.println(team2.getGoal());

        team1.setGoal();
        team1.setGoal();

        System.out.println(team1.getGoal());

    }
}
```